# Using height, width information stored in a TFRecords file to set shape of a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have converted a directory of images and their labels into a TFRecords file, the feature maps include `image_raw`, `label`, `height`, `width` and `depth`. The function is as follows:

```
def convert_to_tfrecords(data_samples, filename):
    def _int64_feature(value):
        return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
    def _bytes_feature(value):
        return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    for fname, lb in data_samples:
        im = cv2.imread(fname, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        image_raw = im.tostring()
        feats = tf.train.Features(
            feature =
            {
                'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_raw),
                'label': _int64_feature(int(lb)),
                'height': _int64_feature(im.shape[0]),
                'width': _int64_feature(im.shape[1]),
                'depth': _int64_feature(im.shape[2])
            }
        )
        example = tf.train.Example(features=feats)
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

Now, I would like to read this TFRecords file to feed a input pipeline. However, since `image_raw` has been flattened, we need to reshape it into the original `[height, width, depth]` size. So how can I get the values of `height`, `width` and `depth` from the TFRecords file? It seems the following code cannot work because `height` is a Tensor without values.

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    feats = {
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'depth': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feats)
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)
    depth = tf.cast(features['depth'], tf.int32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, depth]) # <== not work
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
    return image, label
```

When I read the Tensorflow's official documents, I found they usually pass into a known size, saying `[224,224,3]`. However, I don't like it, because this information has been stored into the TFRecords file, and manually passing into fixed size cannot ensure the size is consistent with the data stored in the file.

So any ideas?

Comment: When you say "`height` is a Tensor without values", what do you mean? At a quick glance, it looks to me like the reading code is ok, but I am wondering whether the writing code is actually storing the right values. In particular, computing the shapes of Tensors without running the graph is best effort, so is im.shape completely defined at the time you write it out? It's hard to tell without seeing more of the writing code.

Comment: The writing code is ok. When writing the tfrecords file, the im.shape is defined, it's [128,128,3] in my program. However, when reading it, since the graph is not running, the `height` is only a Tensor without its value evaluated. You mentioned "without running the graph is best effort", I do agree. But now it is indeed the reason that we don't know the value of Tensor height. So any other option to know the value of `height`?

Answer (score 1):

The `height` returned by `tf.parse_single_example` is a Tensor, and the only way to get its value is to call `session.run()` on it, or similar. However, I think that's overkill.

Since the Tensorflow example is just a protocol buffer (see the documentation), you don't necessarily have to use `tf.parse_single_example` to read it. You could instead parse it yourself and read the shapes you want out directly.

You might also consider filing a feature request on Tensorflow's github issues tracker --- I agree this API seems a bit awkward for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

The function 'tf.reshape' only accept a tensor,not a list of tensors,so you can use the following code:

```
image = tf.reshape(image, tf.stack([height, width, depth]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the numpy array out ot the tensor and reshape using np.resize() passing the dimensions as argument